# save controller class without getting any error?

Tags: apex

Hi this my generated apex code can any help me on writing apex controller i am tring controller class like this but getting error:

```
public class AsyncWwwWebservicexNet1 {
    public class ConversionRateResponse_elementFuture extends System.WebServiceCalloutFuture {
        public Double getValue() {
            wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_element response = (wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_element)System.WebServiceCallout.endInvoke(this);
            return response.ConversionRateResult;
        }
    }
    public class AsyncCurrencyConvertorSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET/', 'wwwWebservicexNet1'};
        public AsyncWwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_elementFuture beginConversionRate(System.Continuation continuation,String FromCurrency,String ToCurrency) {
            wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRate_element request_x = new wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRate_element();
            request_x.FromCurrency = FromCurrency;
            request_x.ToCurrency = ToCurrency;
            return (AsyncWwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_elementFuture) System.WebServiceCallout.beginInvoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              AsyncWwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_elementFuture.class,
              continuation,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate',
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET/',
              'ConversionRate',
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET/',
              'ConversionRateResponse',
              'wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_element'}
            );
        }
    }
}

public class wwwWebservicexNet1 {
    public class ConversionRateResponse_element {
        public Double ConversionRateResult;
        private String[] ConversionRateResult_type_info = new String[]{'ConversionRateResult','http://www.webserviceX.NET/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'ConversionRateResult'};
    }
    public class ConversionRate_element {
        public String FromCurrency;
        public String ToCurrency;
        private String[] FromCurrency_type_info = new String[]{'FromCurrency','http://www.webserviceX.NET/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] ToCurrency_type_info = new String[]{'ToCurrency','http://www.webserviceX.NET/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'FromCurrency','ToCurrency'};
    }
    public class CurrencyConvertorSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET/', 'wwwWebservicexNet1'};
        public Double ConversionRate(String FromCurrency,String ToCurrency) {
            wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRate_element request_x = new wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRate_element();
            request_x.FromCurrency = FromCurrency;
            request_x.ToCurrency = ToCurrency;
            wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate',
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET/',
              'ConversionRate',
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET/',
              'ConversionRateResponse',
              'wwwWebservicexNet1.ConversionRateResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.ConversionRateResult;
        }
    }
```

My Controller class:

```
public class currencyconvert{
public string fromcurrency{get;set;}
public string tocurrency{get;set;}
public double result{get;set;}

 public List<SelectOption> getCountrycodes() {
        List<SelectOption> countrycodes = new List<SelectOption>();
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('AFA','AFA'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('INR','INR'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('RUB','RUB'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('USD','USD'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('ZWD','ZWD'));
        return countrycodes;
    }

 public List<SelectOption> getCountry() {
        List<SelectOption> countrycodes = new List<SelectOption>();
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('VUV','VUV'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('TTD','TTD'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('TWD','TWD'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('USD','USD'));
        countrycodes.add(new SelectOption('AFA','AFA'));
        return countrycodes;
    }

public double convert(){
wwwWebservicexNet1 web = new wwwWebservicexNet1();
result = web.ConversionRate(fromcurrency,tocurrency);
return null;
}
}
```

error:

```
Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [wwwWebservicexNet1].ConversionRate(String, String) at line 30 column 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont want to write the whole class for you but the error you are getting is because the function `ConversionRate` is under class `CurrencyConvertorSoap`  which is in turn under class `wwwWebservicexNet1`. So you should create instance of the inner class then call the function. Something like this -

```
wwwWebservicexNet1.CurrencyConvertorSoap   web = new wwwWebservicexNet1.CurrencyConvertorSoap();
result = web.ConversionRate(fromcurrency,tocurrency);
```

Comment: Nice, I figured it would be because he needed to use a number type.